# Spike of the sleeper

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> We can't both be King of this land,
>   even if you have four in hand.
>   Around your throat,
>   find my ways of deceit,
>   forever connected, don't miss a beat.
>   Let's meet under the 203,
>   twin engines will make short work for me.
>   During my atrocities,
>   you will twist with defeat,
>   to end the tide, would be quite a feat.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are

> a TIE.

We can't both be King of this land,

> I wondered about K-NOT or something to do with "TIE-LAND", but unsurprisingly OP confirms that neither is what they had in mind. Perhaps, in view of the latest hint in comments, this is about a game or sport; if the game is tied then no one has won (hence "is King")? (Perhaps the game is chess, which has kings -- though the usual word there is "draw" rather than "tie".)

even if you have four in hand.

> One kind of tie knot is called a "four-in-hand".

Around your throat,

> This is where ties are generally placed.

find my ways of deceit,

> (not sure what's going on here, though "decEIT" ends with TIE backwards)

forever connected, don't miss a beat.

> Connected, that is, by a *musical* TIE. (Thanks to @Hellion for suggesting this in comments.)

Let's meet under the 203,

> No idea, except that it seems some cable TIEs are 203mm long for some reason. (4/5 of an inch, I guess.) Oh, and the Unicode symbol for one kind of tie (used e.g. in ancient Greek to indicate that a group of letters forms one word rather than two, and in IPA to indicate the absence of a break) which it calls UNDERTIE) is 0x203F; this features both "under" and "203" but that trailing F is important :-).

twin engines will make short work for me.

> TIE fighters in *Star Wars* are so called because of their Twin Ion Engines.

During my atrocities,

> AtrociTIEs.

you will twist with defeat,

> Apparently (thanks to Rubio in comments) a reference to twist TIEs, though I don't understand what defeat has to do with this.

to end the tide, would be quite a feat.

> OP's latest hint in comments suggests that the "end" is the last *two* letters DE, with TI left over. I confess I don't see how to get TIE out of this, though; it seems like it would need E to mean "feat" or something.

... Oh, I forgot to say anything about the title.

> I'm not sure about the "spike", but a sleeper is the same thing as a railway TIE.

Comment: You are correct! 

The four in hand, throat, deceit, twin engines and atrocities clues are all correct, the rest are good guesses though :)

Comment: I response to your speculations, they're unfortunately not on the right track. The lines are separate, each one holds it's own clue/hint.

I don't know if they're maybe too obscure but I'm sure once they're solved you'll see I wasn't trying to obfuscate much.

The 'land' in the first line isn't referring to a literal land, King is a big hint here.

The '203' line has another key component, It's not just about the number alone.

Comment: "Forever connected, don't miss a beat" could be referring to a [musical tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(music)).

Comment: Nice idea! Could well be. (I'm embarrassed not to have thought of it.)

Comment: [ROT47](https://www.browserling.com/tools/rot47): H:=56C DA64F=2E:@?Di  EH:DE =:?6 >2J C676C6?46 9EEADi^^6?]H:<:A65:2]@C8^H:<:^%H:DE0E:6 \ =2DE =:?6[ E:56 \5 :D E:6[ E9@F89 ?@E9:?8 :? E96 =:?6 DF886DED 5@:?8 E92E]

Comment: @Rubio yeah, could be right about twisting. The other one is more or less the same as something already in my paragraph of speculations, which OP says were all wrong :-).

Comment: @Hellion is correct :)

Comment: @Rubio Twist is correct, Tide is very close :)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Your edit with the title is correct :)

I could've put these in one comment but I can only use one tag each time.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan 203 is correct, Tide is VERY close, to the point I feel the solution in my head sounds ridiculous now. King is the only line you haven't done but again maybe it's just the way I thought it out. I explained the solution to my wife and she gave me *a look* which says it all.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You are literally two clues away from finishing and one of them is very close as it is, would you like me to edit in the correct two as it seems we're at an impass? I bet you're fed up of my puzzles now lol.

Comment: Not fed up of your puzzles. But I haven't figured out what you had in mind for "can't both be king" and it doesn't look as if anyone else has either, and likewise for the tide. Feel free to edit in the intended answers (preferably in a way that doesn't make it look as if I found them), or tell me, or offer more hints. Or to leave it as is since, y'know, I haven't in fact solved everything :-).

Comment: I would prefer to nudge in the right direction although my wife thinks I was a little too far out of the box with some of these :)

HINT #1: Black and White
HINT #2: The 'end' is half.

Comment: Well, I have a kinda-plausible guess for "can't both be king". Still well in the dark about ending the tide, though.

Comment: The King one is correct, as Stalemate is another word for Tie. I was just going for the 'Ti' being 'tie' which apparently doesn't work as well as I thought.